# Python. Как записать в новый csv файл первый столбец из другого csv файла

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Дан csv файл с такими данными:

```
Col1; col2; col3; col4; col5
1;2;3;4;5
12;13;14;15;16
31;32;33;34;35
```

Необходимо на Python сделать новый csv файл в котором были бы значения только из первого столбца:

```
1
12
31
```

Comment: А что у вас не плучилось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
filepath = r"in.csv"
f = open("out.csv", "w")
with open(filepath, "r", newline="") as file:
    for row in file:
        a = row.split(';')
        f.write(a[0] + '; \n' )
f.close()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает!

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd

(pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/input.csv', usecols=[0], sep=';', skipinitialspace=True)
   .to_csv(r'/path/to/output.csv', sep=';', header=False, index=False))
```

Результат:

```
1
12
31
```

Comment: большое спасибо, все работает -)